# Using TryGetValue() in LINQ?

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, tryparse, out-parameters, trygetvalue

This code works, but is inefficient because it double-lookups the `ignored` dictionary. How can I use the dictionary `TryGetValue()` method in the LINQ statement to make it more efficient?

```
IDictionary<int, DateTime> records = ...

IDictionary<int, ISet<DateTime>> ignored = ...

var result = from r in records
             where !ignored.ContainsKey(r.Key) ||
             !ignored[r.Key].Contains(r.Value)
             select r;
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to declare a variable within the LINQ statement to use for the out parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare the `out` variable before the query :

```
ISet<DateTime> s = null;
var result = from r in records
             where !ignored.TryGetValue(r.Key, out s)
                || !s.Contains(r.Value)
             select r;
```

Be careful of side effects if the query isn't evaluated until later, though...

Comment: This works. I'm guessing make sure you evaluate it while the variable is still in scope, and don't try to use it with parallel LINQ.

Comment: @Joe, precisely... that would have unpredictable effects

Comment: Note that in C# 7.3 it's now available to initialize the variable inline, such that `where !ignored.TryGetValue(r.Key, out var s) || !s.Contains(r.Value)`

Comment: @Caramiriel Can't see how that helps.

Answer (score 18):

(My answer concerns the general case of using `TrySomething( TInput input, out TOutput value )` methods (like `IDictionary.TryGetValue( TKey, out TValue )` and `Int32.TryParse( String, out Int32 )` and so it does not directly answer the OP's question with the OP's own exmaple code. I'm posting this answer here because this QA is currently the top Google result for "linq trygetvalue" as of March 2019).

When using the extension method syntax there are at least these two approaches.

### 1. Using C# value-tuples, `System.Tuple`, or anonymous-types:

Call the `TrySomething` method first in a `Select` call, and store the outcome in a value-tuple in C# 7.0 (or anonymous-type in older versions of C#, note that value-tuples should be preferred due to their lower overhead):

Using C# 7.0 value-tuples (recommended):

```
// Task: Find and parse only the integers in this input:
IEnumerable<String> input = new[] { "a", "123", "b", "456", ... };

List<Int32> integersInInput = input
    .Select( text => Int32.TryParse( text, out Int32 value ) ? ( ok: true, value ) : ( ok: false, default(Int32) ) )
    .Where( t => t.ok )
    .Select( t => t.value )
    .ToList();
```

This can actually be simplified by taking advantage of another neat trick where the `value` variable is in-scope for the entire `.Select` lambda, so the ternary expression becomes unnecessary, like so:

```
// Task: Find and parse only the integers in this input:
IEnumerable<String> input = new[] { "a", "123", "b", "456", ... };

List<Int32> integersInInput = input
    .Select( text => ( ok: Int32.TryParse( text, out Int32 value ), value ) ) // much simpler!
    .Where( t => t.ok )
    .Select( t => t.value )
    .ToList();
```

Using C# 3.0 anonymous types:

```
// Task: Find and parse only the integers in this input:
IEnumerable<String> input = new[] { "a", "123", "b", "456", ... };

List<Int32> integersInInput = input
    .Select( text => Int32.TryParse( text, out Int32 value ) ? new { ok = true, value } : new { ok = false, default(Int32) } )
    .Where( t => t.ok )
    .Select( t => t.value )
    .ToList();
```

Using .NET Framework 4.0 `Tuple<T1,T2>`:

```
// Task: Find and parse only the integers in this input:
IEnumerable<String> input = new[] { "a", "123", "b", "456", ... };

List<Int32> integersInInput = input
    .Select( text => Int32.TryParse( text, out Int32 value ) ? Tuple.Create( true, value ) : Tuple.Create( false, default(Int32) ) )
    .Where( t => t.Item1 )
    .Select( t => t.Item2 )
    .ToList();
```

### 2. Use an extension method

I wrote my own extension method: `SelectWhere` which reduces this to a single call. It should be faster at runtime though it shouldn't matter.

It works by declaring its own `delegate` type for methods that have a second `out` parameter. Linq doesn't support these by default because `System.Func` does not accept `out` parameters. However due to how delegates work in C#, you can use `TryFunc` with *any* method that matches it, including `Int32.TryParse`, `Double.TryParse`, `Dictionary.TryGetValue`, and so on...

To support other `Try...` methods with more arguments, just define a new delegate type and provide a way for the caller to specify more values.

```
public delegate Boolean TryFunc<T,TOut>( T input, out TOut value );

public static IEnumerable<TOut> SelectWhere<T,TOut>( this IEnumerable<T> source, TryFunc<T,TOut> tryFunc )
{
    foreach( T item in source )
    {
        if( tryFunc( item, out TOut value ) )
        {
            yield return value;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Task: Find and parse only the integers in this input:
IEnumerable<String> input = new[] { "a", "123", "b", "456", ... };

List<Int32> integersInInput = input
    .SelectWhere( Int32.TryParse ) // The parse method is passed by-name instead of in a lambda
    .ToList();
```

If you still want to use a lambda, an alternative definition uses a value-tuple as the return type (requires C# 7.0 or later):

```
public static IEnumerable<TOut> SelectWhere<T,TOut>( this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T,(Boolean,TOut)> func )
{
    foreach( T item in source )
    {
        (Boolean ok, TOut output) = func( item );

        if( ok ) yield return output;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Task: Find and parse only the integers in this input:
IEnumerable<String> input = new[] { "a", "123", "b", "456", ... };

List<Int32> integersInInput = input
    .SelectWhere( text => ( Int32.TryParse( text, out Int32 value ), value ) )
    .ToList();
```

This works because C# 7.0 allows variables declared in an `out Type name` expression to be used in other tuple values.

Answer (score 1):

Using an external variable, you don't need to worry about it going out of scope because the LINQ expression is a **closure** that will keep it alive. However to avoid any conflicts, you could put the variable and expression in a function:

```
public IEnumerable GetRecordQuery() {
    ISet<DateTime> s = null;
    return from r in records
           ... 
}

...

var results = GetRecordQuery();
```

That way, only the query has access to the `s` variable, and any other queries (returned from separate calls to `GetRecordQuery`) will each have their own instance of the variable.